# Build failed on Jenkins machine but runs fine on my local machine

Tags: objective-c, xcode, jenkins, unity-game-engine, armv7

I am trying to build iOS Xcode project and I get this error. Please suggest. I am trying to build using command line. It works fine on my local machine OSX 10.9.2 and Xcode 5.1.1

**Configurations:**

> ```
>     Ld /Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/_/build/\ Dev.app/\ Dev normal armv7
>     cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/_/ios/modules/
>     export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
>     export
> ```

**Paths:**

```
PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/local/bin"
```

> ```
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
> ```
>
> -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/*/build -L/Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/*/ios/modules//Pods//Vendor/libidn -L/Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/*/ios/modules//Pods/GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK
>   -L/Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/*/ios/modules//../../../unity/exports/iOS/Device/Libraries
>   -L/Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/*/ios/modules//lib/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/*/build -F../../lib/comScore -F/Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/_/ios/modules/ -F\\"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks\\"
>   -F/Users/ksota/Desktop -F/Users/ksota/Documents/Git/_client_ios/modules/ -filelist /Users/buildx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-fhknaihaumvqzygratthmtqcvsuj/Build/Intermediates/.build/Release-iphoneos/UnityDevice.build/Objects-normal/armv7/\

**Log where i think GoogleAnalytics kicks in:**

> Dev.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -lGoogleAnalyticsServices -liconv
>   -lidn -lresolv -lsqlite3 -lxml2 -lz -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework
>   CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework
>   CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework MediaPlayer -framework
>   MobileCoreServices -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework
>   QuartzCore -framework Security -framework Social -framework
>   SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework comScore
>   -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework AdSupport -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreTelephony
>   -framework Social -framework Foundation -framework UIKit

**Log for Unity:**

```
 -lPods-UnityDevice -licucore -liPhone-lib -lsqlite3.0 -framework NewRelicAgent -framework Accounts -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/buildx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-fhknaihaumvqzygratthmtqcvsuj/Build/Intermediates/.build/Release-iphoneos/UnityDevice.build/Objects-normal/armv7/\
> Dev_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/_/build/\
> Dev.app/\ Dev
>
```

**Warning generated for PIE:**

> ```
> ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in -[GHAnalyticsVideoEvent validate] from /Users/buildx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-fhknaihaumvqzygratthmtqcvsuj/Build/Intermediates/.build/Release-iphoneos/UnityDevice.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GHAnalyticsVideoEvent.o.
> ```
>
> To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with
>   -Wl,-no_pie

**Linker error:**

> ```
> ld: internal error: atom not found in symbolIndex(__Z23UnityReorientQuaternionffff) for architecture armv7
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
> ```

**Result**:

> ```
> The following build commands failed:
>   Ld /Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/_/build/\ Dev.app/\ Dev normal armv7
> (1 failure)
> Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
> Build step 'Upload to Testflight' marked build as failure
> Archiving artifacts
> ```

Comment: Before more people can help you, you will need to re-write your question.  Simply posting a log asking for help is not enough, particularly when the log is long and not well formatted. Please consider trimming it and/or breaking it up into easier to understand parts. You should also restate the information in the title in the question and add some explanations.  How are you building on your own machine?

Comment: Thanks for the advise @jwernerny, I have edited the log. Linker error with symbolIndex(__Z23UnityReorientQuaternionffff) causes this.